# What's the right UI of a dropdown when it's disabled?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, accessibility, dropdown

There are several settings that users need to go through, one of them is selecting a model. By default, a model is pre-selected in the dropdown field. However, if the user expands the advanced options and toggles language identification, the model dropdown becomes disabled.
[image]

In this scenario, would it be best to disable the model dropdown while keeping the selected item inside (even though it won't have any effect). So that users could come back easily
[image]

Or

Disable the dropdown without any selection in it, just a grey bar. To avoid confusion
[image]

Or are there better options than these two?

Comment: Does Model become disabled because it is no longer a relevant attribute when Language Identification is set to On? If that's true, then the blank disabled fields are correct. Otherwise, can you explain why the user shouldn't be allowed to change their Model selection?

Answer (score 2):

Both variants are not very clear. There is no direct explanation why the dropdowns are disabled and it leaves people guessing what is going on. Without text the (disabled) dropdown can look broken and with text there is a contrast issue.

Better is to hide the disabled dropdowns as they are irrelevant for the chosen state of the form. In your case this can be done by switching between the fields that are relevant/enabled. See images below how.

The state of the dropdowns (disabled/enabled) is defined by a toggle button below them. This is non-logical for users that try to makes sense of the form reading it from top to bottom. Add the toggle button above the fields and toggle the fields below it. In your current design the language selection dropdown shares the label of the toggle button, it doesn't have its own label but should have one. So basically you can make a very simple change that improves flow and accessibility at once:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before, but wouldn't it make sense to hide the arrow when the dropdown is disabled?

If the selection has an effect but can't be changed, you would use the first example.

If the selection has no effect, you should hide the dropdowns instead of leaving them blank, as that looks confusing. I've seen this behaviour quite often.